# .htaccess comingsoon page

Tags: .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to redirect all users to a coming soon page whilst allowing my ip address to use the application normally for testing purposes. I am using this part .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|html)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /coming-soon.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

It works fine and redirects everyone apart my ip to the coming-soon.html page. But it seems that the url_rewrites aren't working so MVC paths seem to have been disabled. Not sure what's wrong.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|html)$
   RewriteRule (.*)$ /coming-soon.html [R=302,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```